# All endings are beginnings

Tags: riddle

> *I never let you down,*
>   *And I make you laugh like a clown.*
>   *I point out your mistakes,*
>   *But our true bond never breaks.*
>   *Together we ascend,*
>   *I'm an end, an end !!!*

Who am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quite literal take on this is you are a

> friend

I never let you down, And I make you laugh like a clown.

> Friends are there for each other and often have fun together.

I point out your mistakes, But our true bond never breaks. Together we ascend,

> True friends offer helpful criticism without risking their relationship. Hopefully friends rise together.

I'm an end, an end !!!

> **Fri** (the end of a common work week) + **end**.
>
>   Also Ak19's comment [A hint: Tomorrow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85395/all-endings-are-beginnings#comment248563_85397) was posted on Thu Jun 27 2019.

Comment: Wow! Excellent "Friend"!

Comment: @Ak19 - I tip my hat to you!

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> a balloon?

*I never let you down,*

> It goes up, not down.

*And I make you laugh like a clown.*

> Filled with laughing gas.

*I point out your mistakes,*

> A note from a teacher/examiner might be enclosed in a "balloon" of ink to be seen more easily.

*But our true bond never breaks.*

> The string on the balloon?

*Together we ascend,*

> A hot air balloon can take you up into the sky.

*I'm an end, an end !!!*

> A balloon ends when you burst it?

Comment: Sorry it's not. Also in the 2nd line, there is *I never let*  **you** *down*

Comment: A hint: Tomorrow....

Answer (score 0):

A very obvious answer:

Are you

> Rick Astley?

*I never let you down*

> Reference to the second line of the chorus of his top hit, Never Gonna Give You Up.

*And I make you laugh like a clown*

> Never Gonna Give You Up has become a meme, and people laugh when they get rickrolled.

*I point out your mistakes*

> Never Gonna Give You Up was supposed to be a love song, but ended up being a meme. Rick Astley himself pointed out the mistake, and he did not enjoy the concept of rickrolling at first.

*But our true bond never breaks*

> Third and fifth lines of the chorus of Never Gonna Give You Up - *Never gonna run around and desert you*, *Never gonna say goodbye*

*Together we ascend*

> Rick Astley has increased in popularity, and your happiness and laughter also 'ascends'.

*I'm an end, an end*

> This article, https://theprovince.com/entertainment/music/you-can-now-rickroll-people-who-ask-for-your-phone-number, mentions that you can now rickroll people by a phone number, marking the end of an era.